# Исполняймые  Python-программы в windows (с exe разширением)

Tags: python

Подскажите. пожалуйста, как можно скомпилировать `.py` в `.exe` и чтоб программы висели скрыто как сервисы до определенного момента (к примеру по таймеру или сочетаниям клавиш)?

Answer (score 1):

По первой части. Советую pyinstaller - "компилирует" в один исполняемый файл. На мой взляд этот вариант самый лучший. Установка проста:

```
python setup.py install
python Configure.py
```

Создание спецификации

```
python Makespec.py --onefile ..\proj_name\src\proj_name.py
```

Пример билдящего батника:

```
set home=%cd%
cd /d "c:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-1.5.1\"
python Build.py proj_name\proj_name.spec
copy proj_name\dist\proj_name.exe %home%\proj_name.exe
cd /d %home%
```

По поводу второй части не совсем понятно. Наверно вам нужно что бы окно консоли не появлялось при исполнении. Для этого нужно поправить файл спецификации pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

Лучшее из того, что я использовал: [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Давайте-ка уточним, а какая у вас версия питона? Для третьей нет ни py2exe, ни pyinstaller, если не ошибаюсь. Для третьей только cx_Freeze.